# A thread only reads and a thread only modifies. Does this variable also need a mutex with linux c?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I came across a question. I found a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797891/is-is-necessary-to-create-a-mutex-for-a-read-only-thread-and-a-write-only-thread) , but after I read it, I felt that I didn't get the answer I wanted. In addition, I wanted to add a comment under the question, but I didn't have permission at present.(50 reputations)

my question: I have 2 thread, thread 1 just modify variable var_A at any time, thread 2 will execute the loop.When thread 2 reaches a certenin step and finds var_A = 1, it will execute action 1. If it finds var_A = 2, it will execute action 2. In this case, I also need to add a mutex?

If adding thread 3 needs to do something similar to thread 2, but only access the value of var_A without modifying it, do I need to add a mutex at this moment?

According to the answers to the above similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797891/is-is-necessary-to-create-a-mutex-for-a-read-only-thread-and-a-write-only-thread) , if the variable is not a single byte type but a multi byte type, I need to add a mutex lock, because it may be suitable for reading and modify a part of var_A. But now I'm just var_A of char type. I want to make sure that I don't need to add a mutex in this case.

Comment: You probably don't need a mutex in that case. But you still may need synchronisation if you want to guarantee that thread 2 sees every change in the value of var_A.

Comment: The rule of thumb: 

You do not need mutex if the read and modify operations are atomic (multibyte operations can be atomic as well). If any is not you need to use some interprocess synchronization mechanisms (for example mutex)

Comment: @kaylum When var_A changes, thread 2 does not need to get the value of var_A immediately. Thread 2 just reads it when it needs to get it.

Comment: @0___________ Here, var_ A is a global variable.

Comment: "_I felt that I didn't get the answer I wanted_" - How so? It looks like that answer describes the same thing as kaylum and  0___________ mentions. "_I want to make sure that I don't need to add a mutex in this case_" - No, an `_Atomic char` will do fine.

Comment: @guoyanzhang it does not matter if modified object is global or local. Operations have to be atomic or IPC synchronization is needed